# Using str_detect on data frame column values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I have a data frame 'fol_all' with field 'folno'.  I have a list called string_detect with list of strings I want to flag in fol_all if they are present in folno.

```
folno <- c('123denied', 'attached_as_test', 'dept_224', 'bulked_up', 'wsd2273')
fol_all <- data.frame(folno)

string_detect <- c('denied', 'attach', 'bulk')

folno <- folno %>% 
  mutate(folno_flag = case_when(str_detect(folno, string_detect)) == T ~ 1, T == 0)
```

In this example, rows 1, 2, and 4 would return a 1 and the rest a 0.

I get the following error - please help.

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first create the regex-pattern to be applied to the column, e.g.

```
 string_detect <- paste(c('denied', 'attach', 'bulk'), collapse = "|")
```

Then you need to adjust your `case_when` code:

```
folno <- fol_all %>% 
  mutate(folno_flag = case_when(
    str_detect(folno, string_detect) ~ 1, 
    TRUE ~ 0 ))
```

Result:

```
             folno folno_flag
1        123denied          1
2 attached_as_test          1
3         dept_224          0
4        bulked_up          1
5          wsd2273          0
```

You do not need `str_detect(folno, string_detect)) == T` because the statement basically says, if `str_detect(folno, string_detect))` evaluates to True, then 1, 0 otherwise.

Whole code:

```
folno <- c('123denied', 'attached_as_test', 'dept_224', 'bulked_up', 'wsd2273')
fol_all <- data.frame(folno)

string_detect <- paste(c('denied', 'attach', 'bulk'), collapse = "|")

fol_all %>% 
  mutate(folno_flag = case_when(
    str_detect(folno, string_detect) ~ 1, 
    TRUE ~ 0 ))
```

Comment: Thank Julian.  I get the following error.  Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
In addition: Warning message:
In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: I added the whole code I used using your example, it works for me without the error.

Comment: TY - that works .  How would I modify to ignore case?

Comment: I tried the following to ignore case, but all the folno_flag came out as 0.  fol_all %>% 
  mutate(folno_flag = case_when(
    str_detect(folno, fixed(string_detect, ignore_case = T)) ~ 1, 
    TRUE ~ 0 ))